# Add-CMDeploymentType warning

Tags: powershell, sccm

Im using poweshell to automate creating applications in SCCM 2012, distributing content and deploying them once created.

I have the following code:

```
   New-CMApplication -name $appname -Manufacturer $manu -SoftwareVersion $ver
```

Which works fine.
However.

```
Add-CMDeploymentType -MsiInstaller -applicationName $appname -AutoIdentifyFromIntallationFile -InstallationFileLocation $content -ForceForUnknownPublisher $true
```

Gives me a warning " Failed to get install type's technology and it won't create the deployment type.

As far as I can tell from other sites, I shouldn't need to specifiy and more than that. I've experimented with adding more options on the end but none seem to make a difference.

There isnt very much out there about this error - has anyone got past it before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually gave up on this - As you say - Add-CMDeployment type is completely useless. There was nothing online anywhere that described this error, or how to use it properly - an Application with no detection is pointless and adding it manually later defeats the point in trying to automate it.

[PowerShell centre](http://www.powershellcenter.com/index.php/powershell-commands/30-add-cmdeploymenttype) had some examples of how it could be used but neither of these worked...

This link was pretty useful and has everything I needed to create an application without powershell.

[link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/one_line_of_code_at_a_time/archive/2011/06/14/how-to-create-a-basic-app-using-the-configuration-manager-2012-beta-2-sdk.aspx)

a bit long but the code was...

```
Public Sub create_SCCM_application(appname As String, version As String, content_location As String, filename As String, manu As String)

    Try
        Dim appID As ObjectId = New ObjectId("ScopeId_devscope", "Application_" & Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        Dim app As New Application(appID)

        app.Title = appname
        app.Version = "1.0"
        app.Publisher = manu
        app.SoftwareVersion = version
        app.AutoInstall = True


        Dim dinfo As New AppDisplayInfo
        dinfo.Title = appname
        dinfo.Version = version

        dinfo.Language = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name
        app.DisplayInfo.Add(dinfo)


        Dim dtID As ObjectId = New ObjectId("ScopeId_devscope", "DeploymentType_" & Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        Dim dt As New DeploymentType(dtID, MsiInstallerTechnology.TechnologyId)
        dt.Title = appname & " Deployment type"
        dt.Version = "1.0"


        app.DeploymentTypes.Add(dt)

        Dim installer As MsiInstaller = dt.Installer
        Dim fakecode As Guid = Guid.NewGuid
        installer.ProductCode = "{" & fakecode.ToString & "}"
        installer.InstallCommandLine = "msiexec /i " & filename
        installer.UninstallCommandLine = "msiexec /x " & filename
        installer.AllowUninstall = True
        installer.ExecuteTime = 30
        installer.MaxExecuteTime = 30
        installer.ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.System
        installer.UserInteractionMode = UserInteractionMode.Hidden
        installer.DetectionMethod = DetectionMethod.ProductCode
        installer.ProductVersion = version



        Dim appcont As Content = New Content
        installer.Contents.Add(appcont)
        appcont.Location = content_location
        Dim msifile As New ContentFile
        msifile.Name = "_temp.msi"
        appcont.Files.Add(msifile)


        Dim appxml As XDocument = SccmSerializer.Serialize(app, True)
        Dim appinstance As ManagementObject = Nothing
        Dim path As ManagementPath = New ManagementPath("SMS_Application")
        Dim options As New ObjectGetOptions
        Dim appClass As ManagementClass = Nothing

        Dim scope As ManagementScope = New ManagementScope("\\devserver\root\Sms\Site_devsitecode")
        appClass = New ManagementClass(scope, path, options)
        appinstance = appClass.CreateInstance()
        appinstance.Properties("SDMPackageXML").Value = appxml
        appinstance.Put()
    Catch x As System.Exception
        Console.WriteLine(x.Message)
    End Try


End Sub
```

Your question regarding the deployment type behaviour is also wierd - We have that same product and it works from an MSI deployment type.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you'll get `Add-CMDeploymentType` to do much useful -- at least not in its current form.  I once tried and gave up when I noticed that it is missing basic, essential parameters.  [The documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj870953(v=sc.20).aspx) does not even mention, for example, detection of any sort.  There's not much point in using ConfigMgr Applications without detection, and there's not much point in scripting the creation of DeploymentTypes if you still have to define the detection criteria via the UI.

You might get the odd `msi` file configured using the `Add-CMDeploymentType`'s `AddDeploymentTypeByMsiInstallerX` parameter set.  In that case you'd be relying on ConfigMgr to work out the detection logic automagically.  That may work, but [I have had significant issues with the MSI Deployment](https://serverfault.com/questions/708889/what-exactly-is-the-sccm-client-doing-when-it-installs-an-msi-for-a-system#comment879179_708889).  I'd avoid that if possible.

I'm not hopeful that the `Add-CMDeploymentType` will ever become usable.  The object tree that underlies Applications is necessarily complex and really doesn't lend itself to interaction using simple PowerShell cmdlets.  To completely configure an Application there are *hundreds* of properties on *dozens* of objects that you need to access.  Many of those objects are contained in dictionary- and array-like collections that have their own special semantics for accessing them.  You just can't simplify that into a handful of PowerShell cmdlets.

I'm using the types in the following .dlls to interface with ConfigMgr:

- AdminUI.WqlQueryEngine.dll
- Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.dll
- Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.MsiInstaller.dll

As far as I can tell, that is the same API the admin console uses, so you can expect full functionality.  You cannot make the same claims about the PowerShell cmdlets.  So far I have found a way to access everything I've tried through that API using PowerShell.  The basics of accessing that API is documented in the [ConfigMgr SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=29559).  It's fairly straightforward to figure out how those objects work using reflection and some experimentation.

When you retrieve an Application using `Get-CMApplication` you actually get the full object tree with it.  The `SDMPackageXML` object contains a serialized copy of the Application, DeploymentTypes, detection, installers, etc.  `[Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ApplicationManagement.Serialization.SccmSerializer]::DeserializeFromString()` works to deserialize that object so you can inspect it for yourself.